# JQuery with prefix selector issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have these pieces of HTML:

```
<li class="icon iconDelete"><a href="/projects/delete/{id}/" title="Delete this test case."></a></li>
<li class="icon iconActive1"><a href="/projects/disable/{id}/" title="Disable this test case."></a></li>
<li class="icon iconActive0"><a href="/projects/enable/{id}/" title="Enable this test case."></a></li>
```

and

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
<ul class="overlayBox" id="overlayBox">
    <li id="overlayTop"></li>
    <li id="overlayContent">
        <b id="overlayTitle">Title</b><br />
        <p id="overlayText">
        Here comes a very important message for your user.
        Turn this window off by clicking the cross.
        </p>
    </li>
    <li id="overlayBottom"></li>
</ul>
```

I have this piece of JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(function()
    {
        $('a[title|="Enable this "]').click(
            function()
            {
            alert(1);
            $('#overlayTitle').text('Are you sure you want to enable this item?');
            $('#overlayText').text('This will take effect for all parent items this item is assigned to.');
            $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function()
                {
                    $('#overlayBox').animate({'top':'160px'},500);
                });
            }
        ),
        $('a[title|="Disable this "]').click(
            function()
            {
            alert(2);
            $('#overlayTitle').text('Are you sure you want to disable this item?');
            $('#overlayText').text('This will take effect for all parent items this item is assigned to.');
            $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function()
                {
                    $('#overlayBox').animate({'top':'160px'},500);
                });
            }
        ),
        $('a[title|="Delete this "]').click(
            function()
            {
            alert(3);
            $('#overlayTitle').text('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
            $('#overlayText').text('This will take effect for all parent items this item is assigned to.');
            $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function()
                {
                    $('#overlayBox').animate({'top':'160px'},500);
                });
            }
        );
    }
    )
);
```

When I click on one of the link with the title attribute, jQuery goes in all .click() functions (3 alerts will pop up), not only the one for the specified prefix selector.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you not select from part of an attribute. Add classes specific to each link, like `link-enabled`, `link-disable` and `link-delete`.

Then you'll can select like `$(".link-enabled").click()` wich causes less problems and also has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to use the label as selector. You can easily add a class to all related elements and use it as selector. Besides that, I think your code could be shorter by using a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your title may change over time. I'd do this:

```
$('a[title]').click(function(){
  if($(this).closest("li").hasClass("iconDelete")){
    alert(1);
    //put the rest of your code
  }
  if($(this).closest("li").hasClass("iconActive1")){
    alert(2);
    //put the rest of your code
  }
  if($(this).closest("li").hasClass("iconActive0")){
    alert(2);
    //put the rest of your code
  }
});
```

Of course you can separate the code in functions for better readability.

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: I'd recommend you to put different clases to the `a` elements and select them by class, it's a more 'correct' way.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another complete solution:

```
<li class="icon iconDelete"><a href="/projects/delete/{id}/" class="delete" title="Delete this test case."></a></li>
<li class="icon iconActive1"><a href="/projects/disable/{id}/" class="disable" title="Disable this test case."></a></li>
<li class="icon iconActive0"><a href="/projects/enable/{id}/" class="enable" title="Enable this test case."></a></li>

function doAction(action){
   alert(action);
   $('#overlayTitle').text('Are you sure you want to '+action+' this item?');
   $('#overlayText').text('This will take effect for all parent items this item is assigned to.');
   $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
        $('#overlayBox').animate({'top':'160px'},500);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.enable').click(function(){
      doAction('enable');   
   });
   $('a.disable').click(function(){
      doAction('disable');   
   });
   $('a.delete').click(function(){
      doAction('delete');   
   });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using the wrong selector.

In the [`Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) (*that you use*) the value needs to be followed by a hyphen (-)

> **Description**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value either equal to a given string
>   or starting with that string **followed
>   by a hyphen (-)**.

You should be using the [`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that works
like this

> **Description**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value **beginning exactly with a given
>   string.**

You should also call the `event.preventDefault()` method so the links do not go through..

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/BdyPB/